# In SonarQube, does Lines to covers should decrease when add tests relatives to the concerned lines to cover?

Tags: sonarqube

1°) Consider that I create new branch , add some code, and somes unit tests

```
so sonar report shows : 50% Coverage on 100 New Lines to cover
```

2°) I add some unit tests  and rebuild

3°) sonar report shows : 55% Coverage on 100 New Lines to cover

Question is :

I do not understand why the coverage increase (from 50% to 55%) but the number of "New Lines to cover" does not decrease, and is still always to 100 ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you write new (real, non-test) code.......and it is 100 (or 200 or 500 or whatever) lines....then whether you write no tests, some tests, a million tests... the new lines to cover will always be 100.    as you write tests..... you (probably) will increase the percentage against those 100 new lines.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that "Lines to cover" are the set of lines that must be covered by unit tests.

so if We like to know how many lines has been covered, we should simply calaculate it :

55% * 100 = 55 Covered Lines and is still 45 Lines to have to cover.